# Como manter 2 elementos na mesma linha Grid bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

Oque preciso é isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque tentei fazer com o conhecimento que tenho em bs4 e grid foi o seguinte:

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
  <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 bg-secondary">
      <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
      <h6 class="card-text text-center">(27) 3974-514</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      segunda linha
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem o os 2 elementos ficam um em baixo do outro, como faço pra eles ficarem na mesma linha?

Até consegui colocar, mas o texto não ficou centralizado por causa do outro elemento, tem que ficar centralizado em relação ao row no caso. 
Também tentei com flex, porém sem sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, quando se esta usando um framework css como o bootstrap, é sempre recomendado escrever o mínimo possível de css.

O Bootstrap tem como padrão todas as divs que não tem uma especificação de tamanho (tipo `col-2`, `col-5`) ter width de 100%. portanto, tu não precisa colocar aquele `col-12` que vc esta usando, então já tirei.

A outra coisa é que a classe do font-awesome ta meio errada com o "s" então tirei o s também, ficou `fa fa-phone fa-lg`.

EDIT: Na verdade isso foi um equivoco meu, estava considerando a versão 4 do fontawesome. Corrigi esse meu erro no snippet

Com essas considerações em mente, a unica coisa que tu tens de fazer é colocar os dois elementos em divs separadas:

- o texto que você quer centralizado dentro de uma div com classe `text-center`;
- o icone dentro de uma div com classe `position-absolute`;

e funciona certinho:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
  <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
  <div class="no-gutters bg-secondary">
    <div class="position-absolute">
      <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="card-text text-center">
      <h6>(27) 3974-514</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>segunda linha</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Como considerações finais, apesar de tu não ter perguntado isso:

1. É bom salientar que o bootstrap4 tem essa utilidade de, se você quiser colocar margem nos dois lados (left e right), você pode usar a classe `mx-3` ou seja, "margem no eixo X de tamanho 3", a mesma logica funciona para o eixo Y, aplicado tanto à margem quanto ao padding.
2. É recomendado que todo o texto do card esteja dentro da div com classe `card-body`, assim eles tem essa margem para a margem do `card` (que eu adicionei também ao snippet, caso não queira ele, só tirar a primeira div).

Comment: Só um detalhe, ele quer o texto centralizado, e o fontawesome dele estava certo, pois estva na versão 5, o que vc fez foi passar o ícone dele para versão antiga que eh a 4....

Comment: falha minha, mas até onde eu vi, funciona nas duas versões

Comment: Acho que vc deveria ver a documentação da versão 5 pra saber o que eh esse "S" que vc tirou...

Comment: verdade, você acha que eu deveria remover a resposta? sendo que no final das contas não respondi a pergunta dele...

Comment: Jovem isso fica a seu critério, vc pode editar, remover, ou deixar como esta. só te dei uma dica sobre a nova versão da font. Se vc acha que a sua resposta responde ao autor da pergunta ou que pode ajudar outra pessoa com problemas semelhantes deixe-a ai... vc decide isso...

Comment: Gosto de usar as classes do bootstrap, só removi o textcenter da div que tem o telefone, é redundante

Answer (score 0):

Olha a solução mais simples para isso seria colocando o ícone dentro do `H6` e colocando ele na esquerda com o `float`.

Veja nesse exemplo como ficou. Não mudei nada no seu código, só coloquei o ícone no `h6` e usei `float` como falei.

**OBS:** o **Fontawesome** transforma o `<i>` em `svg`, então sua classe tem que pegar o `svg` e não o `<i>`

```css
h6 > svg {
    float: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Pizzaria 1</h5>
  <hr class="ml-3 mr-3">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 bg-secondary">

      <h6 class="card-text text-center"><i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg"></i>(27) 3974-514</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      segunda linha
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas ai ele nao fica centralizado 100%, fica um pouco pra direita, por causa do espaço ocupado pelo icone

Comment: Eu coloquei uma margin para ajeitar isso, porem pensei que seria possivel colocar ele centralizado em relacao ao elemento parente

Comment: Igor usando position Absolut como o dvd falou vc consegue "tirar" esse espaço que o ícone ocupa